# Trying to move a block of bytes (memory) to a different address in assembly

Tags: assembly, stack

I can't find out what is the problem with the code?
It loops the procedure and doesn't stop when the register si is equal to the number of bytes i want to move (number.

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
Stack 100h
DATASEG

  number db 3
  addressOne db 0
  addressTwo db 5

 CODESEG
 proc move 
 push bp
 mov bp,sp

 mov si,0

 L1:
    mov ax,[word ptr addressOne+si]
    mov [word ptr addressTwo+si],ax
    inc si

    cmp si,[word ptr number]
    JB L1
  pop bp
  ret 6
  endp move


 start:
  mov ax, @data
  mov ds, ax
 call move



  quit:
 mov ax, 4C00h
 int 21h
  End    start
```

Comment: try to change `number db 3` to `number dw 3`

Comment: or change `cmp si,[word ptr number]` to `cmp si, number`

Comment: I did it but it still loops the loop inside the procedure even after si is bigger than       [number]

Comment: also, are you sure about `jb l1` shouldn't it be `jl l1`?

Comment: jl is for signed numbers and I am using unsigned numbers (number is positive)

Comment: There are several problems with your code. `number` needs to be a word (`dw`) since `si` is a word. `si` needs to be incremented by 2 each iteration since each word you copy is 2 bytes (so the value of `number` should be 6). You need to reserve more space at `addressOne` and `addressTwo` than just 1 byte each, since you're trying to copy 6 bytes.

Comment: So should I make addressOne and addressTwo arrays? I meant to make them as the starting point of the block I'm copying.

Comment: Learn to use [`REP MOVSB`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html).